# Module not found: Error: Package path is not exported from package

Tags: html, reactjs, firebase

Trying to make a singup/login page.

Code:
import firebase from 'firebase';

```
const config = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyCnx2VxuuVmYNeEj22xoyAR0ygS0b1w174",
authDomain: "fir-login-63d60.firebaseapp.com",
projectId: "fir-login-63d60",
storageBucket: "fir-login-63d60.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "524578552249",
appId: "1:524578552249:web:a090dda97d973f861ede68",
measurementId: "G-FX4XELDM9T"
};

const fire = firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

export default fire;

> Error: ERROR in ./src/config/Fire.js 3:0-32 Module not found: Error:
> Package path . is not exported from package

Comment: don't share valid values of your key items.

Comment: Its a demo project, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: which firebase version are you using?

Comment: The firebase version is:  9.6.9